# Delete all files in a certain directory that their names start with a certain string in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, unlink

I want to delete all files that there file names start with the same string in a certain directory, for example I have the following directory:

```
public/
      profile-photo-SDS@we3.png
      profile-photo-KLs@dh5.png
      profile-photo-LSd@sd0.png
      cover-photo-KAS@hu9.png
```

so I would like to apply a function to delete all the files that start with the string `profile-photo` to have at the end the following directory:

```
public/
      cover-photo-KAS@hu9.png
```

I am looking for function like this:

```
fs.unlink(path, prefix , (err) => {

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `glob` npm package: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/profile-photo-*.png", options, function (er, files) {
    for (const file of files) {
         // remove file
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

As Sergey Yarotskiy [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077961/3928341), using a package like `glob` would probably be ideal since that package is already tested and would make filtering files much easier.

That being said, the general algorithmic approach you can take is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { resolve } = require('path');

const deleteDirFilesUsingPattern = (pattern, dirPath = __dirname) => {
  // default directory is the current directory

  // get all file names in directory
  fs.readdir(resolve(dirPath), (err, fileNames) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    // iterate through the found file names
    for (const name of fileNames) {

      // if file name matches the pattern
      if (pattern.test(name)) {

        // try to remove the file and log the result
        fs.unlink(resolve(name), (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`Deleted ${name}`);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

deleteDirFilesUsingPattern(/^profile-photo+/);
```

Comment: This was very helpful to me, I did have to modify the resolve(name) in the unlink to something more like resolve(dirPath + name).